# batch_size and max_time in LSTM Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, data-pipeline

**Background:**
I am trying to model multi-layered LSTM in tensorflow. I am using a common function to unroll the LSTM:

```
tf.nn.dynamic_rnn
```

Here I am using `time_major = True`, so my data has to be of format `[max_time, batch_size, depth]`.

According to my understanding `max_time` is the time step of the series. My input is [224], I am passing into FC layer in the beginning to make it to size of labels

**Question**:

I am using datapipeline to get the labels in batch(32) of one_hot vector(length=70).

70 length vector corresponds to 1 time-step.

So how can I make the input to [32, 32 ,70]? Presently I have [32,70]`(batch_size,num_classes)`.

Please correct my understandings if wrong.

Can I just pass `[1,32,70]`, so that tensorflow detects on its own, that each batch is of time step 1?